# MariaDB query optimizer not using correct index

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, mariadb

I got the following query and it was supposed to use index to speed up but it is using the wrong index image_likes and takes around 60 seconds to execute. If I add use index(image_user_id) then it takes only 0.623 seconds. However I want to make it automatically pick index as this is part of very large application and I can't modify the queries.

```
SELECT * , NULL as image_original_exifdata
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM images
  LEFT JOIN albums ON images.image_album_id = albums.album_id 
  WHERE images.image_user_id='24368'
  AND image_size > 0
  AND images.image_nsfw = 0
  AND (
    albums.album_privacy NOT IN ('private','private_but_link','password','custom')
    OR
    albums.album_privacy IS NULL
    OR
    albums.album_user_id IS NULL
  ) ORDER BY images.image_likes DESC LIMIT 21
) images
LEFT JOIN storages ON images.image_storage_id = storages.storage_id
LEFT JOIN users ON images.image_user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON images.image_category_id = categories.category_id
ORDER BY images.image_likes DESC;
```

I tried creating a multi column index with all columns referenced in this query, but still the optimizer pick the wrong index and takes so long to execute. I tried dumping the database and reloading it again along with optimize table.

Can anyone help me make the optimizer pick the correct index without editing the core SQL statements?

Comment: Please qualify all columns when using `JOIN`.  For example, I need to know what table `image_size` is in.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the multi-column index you tried.

Answer (score 0):

**What to try next**

`images` needs

```
 INDEX(image_user_id, image_nsfw,  -- in either order
       image_nsfw)   -- if it is in that table
```

or

```
 INDEX(image_user_id, image_nsfw,  -- in either order
       image_likes)
```

Don't use `*` if you don't need all the columns from all the joined tables.  It may be inhibiting optimizations, especially the use of "covering" indexes.

**To explain the issue.**  The Optimizer saw

```
 WHERE user_id = constant AND other-stuff
 ORDER BY likes
```

Plan A:  Satisfy some of the `WHERE` by using `INDEX(user_id)`, but have to do a sort later.

Plan B:  Use `INDEX(likes)` to avoid the sort, but run the risk of having to scan too much of the table before 21 desirable rows are found.

The Optimizer does not gather enough statistics to always pick the "right" index.  It is a tough Optimization problem.

Newer versions of MySQL/MariaDB do a better job, but still not perfect.

The indexes I suggested may help.

**What does not work**

Dumping and reloading the table is very unlikely to help at all.  Ditto for `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

`ANALYZE TABLE` *might* help, but it is hit or miss.

"a multi column index with all columns referenced in this query" -- That would be "covering".  Beyond, say, 5 columns, that is rarely worth trying.  In any case, the *order of the columns* in the index is vital to the utility of the index.